# ?JS How to exit from function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, prompt, func

I need to exit from mine.onclick = function so can anyone help me??
I'm new in js!
I tried to write the word game and I need to write the function, when I'm clicking on the button I need to move the button, but its not working 3th time

```
    //creating div  
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHtml = '';
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.classList.add('main');

//creating divsec 
var divsec = document.createElement('div');
divsec.innerHtml = '';
document.body.appendChild(divsec);
divsec.classList.add('submain');

//creating array for words
var arr = prompt("Write your word or sentance here and don't accept your apponent to see that!");
array = arr.split('');
array = array.sort();
console.log(array);
alert("Let's construct the word!");

var main = document.getElementsByClassName('main');
var divsec = document.getElementsByClassName('submain');
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    divsec[0].appendChild(button);
    button.innerHTML = array[i];
    button.onclick = function(){
        mainp = main[0].appendChild(this);
        mainp.onclick = function (){
            divsec[0].appendChild(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the answer you're looking for?

```js
//creating div  
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHtml = '';
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.classList.add('main');

//creating divsec 
var divsec = document.createElement('div');
divsec.innerHtml = '';
document.body.appendChild(divsec);
divsec.classList.add('submain');

//creating array for words
var arr = prompt("Write your word or sentance here and don't accept your apponent to see that!");
array = arr.split('');
array = array.sort();
console.log(array);
alert("Let's construct the word!");

var main = document.getElementsByClassName('main');
var divsec = document.getElementsByClassName('submain');
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    divsec[0].appendChild(button);
    button.innerHTML = array[i];
    button.onclick = function(){
   if (this.parentNode.className === 'main') divsec[0].appendChild(this)
   else main[0].appendChild(this);
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

If it's not, please clarify your question and give an example of what is the desired effect on clicking a single button. I'm also not sure what you mean by exit the function. It seemed fine to me.

You stated that you need a button to move, but you didn't state how does it need to move.

Comment: My code is working but only 2 times, I need to use on click for button.onclick infinite times, I got an error, when I'm clicking 2nd time on button inside div by class submain buttons are changing their place only inside that div but I need to change them into div by class main! Sorry for my English

Comment: I think that I get what you're on about, but I still would prefer a clarification. I don't run into any errors on playcode.io. Can you tell me, how exactly buttons are supposed to move? Left? Right? Subcycle? Describe the process or input/output relation, please. I'll try to help when I've time, since I'm occupied atm. You might try to apply innerHTML method, though. It may solve your problems.

Comment: I'm trying to move my button by onclick event to first div (main) and back to div (divsec) by clicking too.

Comment: ...so, is it supposed to 'toggle' classes on clicking? Yes? (I'll edit my code snippet)